# Apache Cassandra and Windows

Tags: windows, cassandra

What are the fine tuning configuration for Apache Cassandra for windows machine,I have seen "Unable to create new native thread" due to less number of "max user processes" in linux and the one of the solution is [1]
[1]http://vanjikumaran.blogspot.com/2014/01/unable-to-create-new-native-thread-and.html

Therefore, what are the best practices for Apache Cassandra configuration and OS settings for windows?

Comment: Generally speaking, the best practice is not to use Cassandra for production on Windows.  It's practically unheard of, based on what I heard on user discussion lists and other relevant communities.

For creating more threads on Windows, try running Java with an increased stack size using `ss` (stack size) argument, as in `java -Xss 1M`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best practice for "Cassandra on Windows" right now is "don't".  There are a bunch of edge case issues that crop up on Windows because things like file handles behave slightly differently and do not have the same guarantees they do on Linux.

It works well enough to run a dev/test instance on your Windows box for development purposes.  But for anything other than that you should really use Linux, as that is what everyone else uses, and it has the most testing.

Here is a blog post with the current status of Cassandra on Windows:
http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-and-windows-past-present-and-future

Comment: Yes, I have ran the Cassandra for test purpose only to compare the functionality in both OS (windows and Linux)